# Can doFilter and HandlerInterceptorAdapter be used together in single spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Can doFilter and HandlerInterceptorAdapter be used together in single spring application?

I am in SpringMVC application in which doFilters are used already.

I have requirement of updating request params of request and redirect page. I used HandlerInterceptorAdapter to achieve it. But looks like application is failing after chain.doFilter(req,res)